# CPU consumption when thread is sleeping using Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a server program which polls a database for new requests , I want this polling to be done at 1 minute intervals so , I've set up a Thread.sleep() in the program while loop.
The problem is that whenever this program is supposed to "sleep" the CPU consumption goes up drastically (viz. about 25 - 30%). 
 
Paradoxically, when the program is not dormant and is busy processing requests , the CPU consumption drops to 0.4%. 
I read online and found out that there are performance hits associated with thread.sleep, but I could not find any viable alternative (Thread.wait requires notification on an object, something which I feel is useless in my scenario)

The main loop (when there are no new requests) doesn't do anything, here is a skeleton of all that is being done when the CPU consumption is 25%

-> poll 
 -> No new records ? 
    -> Sleep 
->repeat

Comment: How long are you sleeping for? and what is the rest of the `while` loop doing?

Comment: That is weird. Can you reduce it to a small program that behaves like you describe, and post it here? At the very least, please show us the skeleton of your `sleep` loop (using actual code).

Comment: Please provide the code section where you do the actual sleeping.

Comment: Just making sure - you're not using `Thread.sleep(60)` to sleep for 60 seconds, right? (that would cause a sleep of 60 milliseconds)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check what the CPU consumption is for individual CPU cores. If you are using a 4 core machine, maybe one thread is going rogue and is eating up once core (25%). This usually happens when the thread is in a tight loop.

You could use `Thread.wait` with a timeout (which indeed the `Timer` class does), but my bet is that it won't make any difference. Both `Thread.sleep` and `Thread.wait` changes the threads' state to `not runnable`. Although it depends on your JVM implementation etc., the thread shouldn't consume that much CPU in such situation. So my bet is that there is some bug at work.

Another thing you can do is taking a thread dump and see what the thread is doing when this happens. Use `kill -3` on a Linux box, or use ctrl+break on the java console window if you are using Windows. Then, examine the thread dump that is dumped to the standard output. Then you can be sure if the thread was actually sleeping or was doing something else.

Comment: To be more clear: Threads consume no CPU at all while in `not runnable` state. Not even a tiny bit. This does not depend on implementation.

Answer (score 5):

As many people pointed out, Thread.sleep should and actually does help with dropping the CPU usage drastically. 
I omitted certain facts from my original question as I thought they were not relevant.
The main thread was the producer, there was another thread running asynchronously which was the consumer. It turns out that the "sleep" on this thread was inside some weird condition that wasn't getting triggered properly. So the loop on that thread was never sleeping.
Once the sleep thing was eliminated I went ahead and analyzed it closely to realize the problem.